# restrict filter for some column in datatables

Tags: search, datatables

I have some columns like name, id, phone,.....,action(edit / delete). Now I want to restrict the column filtration for some of the columns. For that I have written some code like :

```
var filterIndexes = [14,3];
$('th', '.select-box-filter').each( function ( i ) {
    if ($.inArray(i, filterIndexes)) {
        this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
        $('select', this).change( function () {
            oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
        });
    }
});
```

But in this case it excludes only the 15th column not the 4rd column. For more information, The value of `filterIndexes` is not static, it contents dynamic value.
Please suggest me where is the issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you are trying to achive exactly with this code? if the objective its only not allow some columns to be not sortable throut fnfilter why not use something like this? $('#tableId').dataTable("aoColumns": [ {"bSearchable": true}, {"bSearchable": false}, etc ]);

Comment: because my columns are not static, it might be {"bSearchable": true}, {"bSearchable": false},null or {"bSearchable": true}, null {"bSearchable": false} etc.